# C directory in Haskell .cabal file

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have this .cabal file:

```
  ...
  main-is:             Main.hs
  other-extensions:    ForeignFunctionInterface
  build-depends:       base >=4.9 && <4.10
  hs-source-dirs:      src/haskell
  c-sources:           src/c/main.c ... 
  default-language:    Haskell2010
```

I have a lots of c source files, all in one directory(src/c), is there a way to add them all without specifying each one? something like a regex:

```
-- I know this won't work
c-sources:           src/c/**
```

Or just including the whole directory:

```
-- I know this won't work
c-source-dirs:      src/c
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try: `c-sources: src/c/*.c`

`**` wildcards were added in Cabal 2.4

Wildcard examples from here: https://www.haskell.org/cabal/users-guide/developing-packages.html?highlight=c%20source#pkg-field-data-files